# Changing difficulty settings in an Unity Pong game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I get "NullReferenceException: Object not set to an instance of an object" error, while trying to get a value from another script.

//first script

```
public class Easy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int difficulty=0;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        difficulty = 0;
        GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(diffchange);
    }

    public void diffchange()
    {
        difficulty = 1;
        SceneManager.LoadScene("5Game");
    }
}
```

//second script

```
public class AIMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject ball;
    public float speed;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (GetComponent<Easy>().difficulty==1)// here is the problem, trying to get the value from the first script
        {
            speed = 200;
        }
        

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
            if (ball.transform.position.y > this.transform.position.y)
            {
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, 1) * speed * Time.deltaTime;

            }
            else
            {
                if (ball.transform.position.y < this.transform.position.y)
                {
                    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, -1) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
                }
                
            }
    }
}
```

I tried to do it in reverse as well. To change the value in the second script from the first, but it didn't work, i think i got the same error.

```
//first script
GetComponent<AIMovement>().difficulty=1;
//second script
public int difficulty=0;
...
if(difficulty==1)
...
```

Comment: Getting a null reference exception on`GetComponent<Easy>().difficulty==1` means that the gameobject does not have an `Easy` component

Comment: `GetComponent` expects the `Easy` to attached to the very same `GameObject` as the `AIMovement` component .. if there is none then you get `null`

Comment: I attached Easy to the same GameObject as AIMovement and I still get null.

Comment: please include the complete stack trace - also ensure there are not maybe any instances of your component you didn't intent to create  .. for instance add a `Debug.Log("Hello!", this);` and check the console how often this is logged and what objects are highlighted if you click once on the log message ... is it really only the expected one(s)?

Comment: stack trace? i'm pretty new here, new to programming as well, so i don't really get the specialised terms. yeah, i'm pretty sure that's the gameobject i needed to attach to, don't think there were others. i don't know how to do what you said lol.

Comment: I solved it. I added static in script 1, public static int difficulty=0; and added in script 2, Easy.difficulty==1;